# Using LESS Hat with Twitter Bootstrap LESS mixins

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

Well, the title pretty much sums up the crux of my question.
I'm in the process of evaluating the possibility of using LESS + LESS Hat mixins (lesshat.com) + Twitter Bootstrap mixins. I would appreciate it if anyone could shed light on potential issues that might crop up. Or if it is advisable to do so in the first place.
Thanks.

Comment: Why even bother with a reply if you're not going to help? I don't have enough experience with LESS to be able to properly determine the potential issues. Just because it can compile successfully doesn't mean there won't be future issues.

Comment: Which features do you require that TBS does not offer?

Comment: Animations would be great to have and less hat seems to have a more comprehensive list of mixins for CSS3 especially transformations.

Comment: I am assuming you have gone over this: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less

Comment: Yes, I have gone through both LESS Hat and Twitter Bootstrap's mixins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is testimony of some potential issues of conflict between them. This is a quote from 4 months ago on the [lesshat site](http://lesshat.com/):

> There is one issue with it, i am using Twitter Bootstrap and csshat
>   and love to add this to the framework. But it conflics [sic] with Twitter
>   Bootstraps styling and wonderd [sic] if this can easily be fixed?

Whether those conflicts have been handled or not in the last 4 months is unknown. I have no personal experience with the two together, so I cannot testify further than the information I found above.

Comment: Thanks. Would appreciate it if you could state the exact url where this statement is located.

Comment: @ephemeron: It's in the discussion section at the very bottom of the home page. Currently it is the second comment from the top, the one made by "FreelanceWebdesignerNL".

Answer (score 5):

New version 2 (Nov 2013) allows you to use LESS Hat without any conflicts by introducing a prefixed version (with `.lh-`). There should be no other issues.

From README at https://github.com/csshat/lesshat/blob/master/README.md:

> **Bootstrap friendly** – You can now use prefixed LESS Hat version and gaily work with Bootstrap. Yeah it's that easy.

Direct download: https://raw.github.com/csshat/lesshat/master/build/lesshat-prefixed.less